# Container/heap Pop() on empty heap

Tags: go, containers, heap

I have used the `container/heap` package to implement a priority queue.  One thing bothers me though.  What should the behaviour of the `interface.Pop()` method be if the heap is empty?  I don't see anything mentioned in the documentation and the source code doesn't seem to be expecting this situation:

```
// Pop removes the minimum element (according to Less) from the heap
// and returns it. The complexity is O(log(n)) where n = h.Len().
// It is equivalent to Remove(h, 0).
//
func Pop(h Interface) interface{} {
        n := h.Len() - 1
        h.Swap(0, n)
        down(h, 0, n)
        return h.Pop()
}
```

Clearly, if `h.Len()` is `0` this is not going to work well.  Is this simply meant to `panic` or is the user expected to always check whether there are any items left?

Comment: It's up to you. You can either return nil, or panic. (I would say it's more proper to let it panic, rather than let the user get a nil return value)

Comment: go deeper and check the methods h.Swap() and down(), they check the limits

Comment: @YandryPozo - `if j1 >= n || j1 < 0 { // j1 < 0 after int overflow`  I think this is a bit different.  And `h.Swap()` is implemented by the underlying `sort.Interface`.

Comment: @JimB - thanks.  Out of curiosity, how do you know this?

Comment: @EduardSemsch; know what? Those are the only 2 possibilities for that method signature. As for panicking, popping off an empty heap is akin to indexing a slice out of bounds (which is probably what will happen underneath), which is a programming error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural behaviour is to panic. This is what the [IntHeap example](https://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/#example__intHeap) does.

As pointed out in the comments, control will not reach `h.Pop()` if `h.Swap()` panics. However, `h.Pop()` can still be called on an empty heap if `heap.Remove()` is given -1 as the index:

```
// Remove removes the element at index i from the heap.
// The complexity is O(log(n)) where n = h.Len().
//
func Remove(h Interface, i int) interface{} {
    n := h.Len() - 1
    if n != i {
        h.Swap(i, n)
        down(h, i, n)
        up(h, i)
    }
    return h.Pop()
}
```

If `h.Swap()` panics on negative indices, `h.Pop()` should also panic for consistency.

Having `h.Swap()` silently ignore negative indices and `h.Pop()` return a default value like `nil` is consistent, but other programmers would find that surprising so I don't recommend it.